# Работа с файлами, С

Tags: c, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка, почему программа не открывает файл. Задача программы ввести сведения о товаре.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <locale.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <string.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    FILE *devices;
    struct measuredvalue {
        char name[50];
        int upperbound;
        int lowerbound;
        int error;
    };
    struct fullname {
        char firstname[50];
        char secondname[50];
        char surname[50];
    };
    struct address {
        char city[50];
        char street[50];
        int numberofhouse;
    };
    struct customer {
        int listnumber;
        struct fullname fname;
        struct address addres;
        int amountofdevices;
    };
    struct DEVICE {
        char name[50];
        float cost;
        int num;
        int num1;
        struct measuredvalue *array;
        struct customer *buyer;
    };
    int number, i, value1, j;
    printf("Кол-во товаров: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    struct DEVICE *mas;
    mas = (struct DEVICE*)malloc(number * sizeof(struct DEVICE));
    if (!mas) {
        printf("Ошибка памяти");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        printf("Наименование товара: ");
        gets(mas[i].name);
        gets(mas[i].name);
        printf("Стоимость товара: ");
        scanf("%f", &mas[i].cost);
        printf("Измеряющие величины: ");
        scanf("%d", &mas[i].num);
        mas[i].array = (struct measuredvalue*)malloc(mas[i].num * sizeof(struct measuredvalue));
        for (j = 0; j < mas[i].num; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &value1);
            switch (value1) {
            case'1':
                strcpy(mas[i].array[j].name, "сила тока");
                break; 
            case'2':
                strcpy(mas[i].array[j].name, "напряжение");
                break;
            case'3':
                strcpy(mas[i].array[j].name, "температура");
                break;
            case'4':
                strcpy(mas[i].array[j].name, "давление");
                break;
            case'5':
                strcpy(mas[i].array[j].name, "кислотность");
                break;
            case'6':
                strcpy(mas[i].array[j].name, "концентрация серы");
                break;
            case'7':
                strcpy(mas[i].array[j].name, "плотность");
                break;
            }
            printf("Верхняя граница: ");
            scanf("%d", &mas[i].array[j].upperbound);
            printf("Нижняя граница: ");
            scanf("%d", &mas[i].array[j].lowerbound);
            printf("Погрешность");
            scanf("%d", &mas[i].array[j].error);
        }
        printf("Кол-во заказчиков: ");
        scanf("%d", &mas[i].num1);
        mas[i].buyer = (struct customer*)malloc(mas[i].num1 * sizeof(struct customer));
        for (j = 0; j < mas[i].num1; j++) {
            mas[i].buyer[j].listnumber = j + 1;
            printf("Фамилия ");
            gets(mas[i].buyer[j].fname.surname);
            printf("Имя ");
            gets(mas[i].buyer[j].fname.firstname);
            printf("Отчество ");
            gets(mas[i].buyer[j].fname.secondname);
            printf("Адрес: ");
            printf("город ");
            gets(mas[i].buyer[j].addres.city);
            printf("улица ");
            gets(mas[i].buyer[j].addres.street);
            printf("дом № ");
            scanf("%d", &mas[i].buyer[j].addres.numberofhouse);
            printf("Кол-во приборов: ");
            scanf("%d", &mas[i].buyer[j].amountofdevices);
        }
    }
    if ((devices = fopen("devices.txt", "w+")) != 0) {
        fprintf(devices, "Кол-во товаров: ");
        fprintf(devices, "%d", &number);
        for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            fprintf(devices, "Наименование товара: ");
            fputs(mas[i].name, devices);
            fprintf(devices, "Стоимость товара: ");
            fprintf(devices, "%f", &mas[i].cost);
            fprintf(devices, "Измеряющие величины: ");
            for (j = 0; j < mas[i].num; j++) {
                fputs(mas[i].array[j].name, devices);
                fprintf(devices, "Верхняя граница: ");
                fprintf(devices, "%d", &mas[i].array[j].upperbound);
                fprintf(devices, "Нижняя граница: ");
                fprintf(devices, "%d", &mas[i].array[j].lowerbound);
                fprintf(devices, "Погрешность");
                fprintf(devices, "%d", &mas[i].array[j].error);
            }
            fprintf(devices, "Кол-во заказчиков: ");
            fprintf(devices, "%d", &mas[i].num1);
            for (j = 0; j < mas[i].num1; j++) {
                fprintf(devices, "%d", mas[i].buyer[j].listnumber);
                fprintf(devices, "Фамилия ");
                fputs(mas[i].buyer[j].fname.surname, devices);
                fprintf(devices, "Имя ");
                fputs(mas[i].buyer[j].fname.firstname, devices);
                fprintf(devices, "Отчество ");
                fputs(mas[i].buyer[j].fname.secondname, devices);
                fprintf(devices, "Адрес: ");
                fprintf(devices, "город ");
                fputs(mas[i].buyer[j].addres.city, devices);
                fprintf(devices, "улица ");
                fputs(mas[i].buyer[j].addres.street, devices);
                fprintf(devices, "дом № ");
                fprintf(devices, "%d", &mas[i].buyer[j].addres.numberofhouse);
                fprintf(devices, "Кол-во приборов: ");
                fprintf(devices, "%d", &mas[i].buyer[j].amountofdevices);
            }
        }
        fclose(devices);
    }
    else { printf("Ошибка открытия файла"); }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

СПАСИБО.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((devices = fopen("devices.txt", "w")) == 0) {
```

При корректном открытии файла `fopen` возвращает **ненулевой** указатель. У вас же считается, что все в порядке, если возвращается 0...

```
if ((devices = fopen("devices.txt", "w")) != NULL) {
```

Так оно правильнее...

Далее, что за странности - файл открыт для записи, вы же в него пишете и тут же читаете - что? Если там ничего этого нет?

```
fprintf(devices, "Кол-во товаров: ");
fscanf(devices, "%d", &number);
```

Тут уж нужно что-то одно выбирать :)

Comment: Спасибо, но файл все равно не открывается.

Comment: См. обновление в ответе.

Comment: Тогда через какую функцию вводить данные в файл с устройства ввода, разве здесь не те же самые функции, что и при работе с консолью?

Comment: Скажите, когда вы вызываете `sqrt(4)` и `sqrt(9)`, вас не удивляет разный результат? *Функции-то те же самые (с)* Хотите выводить на консоль - используйте как параметр `stdout`, читать - `stdin`, но не ваш же файл!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую использовать функцию для ввода сразу в файл.

Comment: Так не бывает. Читайте в переменную, потом записывайте...

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли.